# complex function bounded by $e^{\sqrt{|z|}}$ - complex analysis prelim practice

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that
$$|f(z)|\le e^{\sqrt{|z|}}$$
Let $n(r)$ be the number of zeros of $f$ with modulus less than $r$.

Prove that there exist $A,B\ge0$ such that 
$n(r)\le A+B\sqrt{r}$ for all $r$.

I believe I am supposed to use the argument principle somewhere but how?

Comment: You need to use the jensen Formula for the estimation of the numbers of zeros

Comment: Ah, it seems that will be very helpful. It was not included in the class material, so I will attack the problem again using this.

Comment: You can also check the sections that contain Jensen's Formula in Rudin or Stein-Shakarchi. They prove something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use [Jensen's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula). Assume that your function has a zero of order $\lambda$ at the origin, then since $f \in H(\mathrm{D}(0,R))$ (denotes the open disk of center zero and radius $R$), we have that
$$
\int_0^R \frac{n(r)}{r}dr = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log |f(Re^{i \theta})| d\theta - \log \frac{|f^{(\lambda)}(0)|}{\lambda!} - \lambda \log R
$$
(this one you can obtain applying the formula which assumes $f(0)\neq 0$ to the function $f(z)z^{-\lambda}$).

Next observe that $|f(z)| \leq e^{|z|^{1/2}}$ implies that the growth scale of $f$,
$$
M(r) = \max_{|z|=r} |f(z)|,
$$
satisfies 
$$
\log M(r) \leq \sqrt{r},\qquad r > 0
$$
Hence in the main formula the right hand side is bounded above: for $R=eR'>1$ ($e$ is Euler's constant):
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \log |f(Re^{i \theta})| d\theta - \log \frac{|f^{(\lambda)}(0)|}{\lambda!} - \lambda \log R \leq  \sqrt{R} + A = B \sqrt{R'}+A
$$

Since $n(r)$ is non-decreasing, the left hand side of the main formula is bounded below: 
$$
\int_0^R \frac{n(r)}{r}dr \geq \int_{R'}^{R} \frac{n(r)}{r}dr \geq n(R')\int_{R'}^R \frac{dr}{r} = n(R')
$$

Finally, set $R'=r$ to conclude:
$$
n(r) \leq B\sqrt{r} + A.  
$$